# ArrayAdapter never used ArrayList null and all items appear in single row

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android and I am trying to create a list view using an array adapter, a run method and multi threading. The list displays all the data from an array list as a single row.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{

..
    ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;

    ArrayList<SummaryData> summary;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSpinnerAPI = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAPI);
        mButtonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
        mEditTextResponse = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
        mProgressRequest = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressRequest);

        mButtonSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

  ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggleProgress(true);
        switch (mSpinnerAPI.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
            case 0: // Authenticate
              ...
            case 4: // Get Summary Day
                MovesAPI.getSummary_SingleDay(summaryHandler, "20150418", null);//Date changed to "20150117"
                break;
          ...
            case 10: // Get Storyline Day
                MovesAPI.getStoryline_SingleDay(storylineHandler, "20150418", "20140714T073812Z", false);//Date changed to "20150418" "null changed to"20140714T073812Z"
                break;
          ...
                toggleProgress(false);
                break;
        }

    }

   ...

    private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<StorylineData> result) {
            toggleProgress(false);
                 updateResponse(
                           "Date:\t" + result.get(0).getDate() + "\n"
                           + "-----------Activity 1 Summary--------\t" + "\n"
                           + "Activity:\t" + result.get(0).getActivity().toString() + "\n"//returns 1587 with .getCaloriesIdle()
                      ...
                           + "-----------Activity 2 Summary---------\t" + "\n"
                           + "Activity:\t" + result.get(0).getSummary().get(0).getActivity() + "\n"//returns 1587 with .getCaloriesIdle()
 ...


 + "-----------Segments---------\t" + "\n"
                           + "Type:\t" + result.get(0).getSegments().get(0).getType() + "\n"//returns 1587 with .getCaloriesIdle()

...
        }

    public void updateResponse(final String message) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mButtonSubmit.setText(message);

                StorylineAdapter adapter = new StorylineAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, storylineData);
                mEditTextResponse.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ArrayAdapter class looks like this:

```
public class StorylineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryData>{
    private Context context;
    private Runnable runnable;
private ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;

public StorylineAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SummaryData> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.runnable = runnable;
    this.summary = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);

//Display in the TextView widget
SummaryData summary1 = summary.get(position);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(summary1.getActivity());

return view;
}
}
```

Here is my parser class:

```
public class StorylineData extends ArrayList<StorylineData> {

...Getters/Setters...

/**
 * Parse a {@link org.json.JSONObject} from storyline {@link org.json.JSONArray}, then return the corresponding {@link StorylineData} object.
 *
 * @param jsonObject : the storyline JSON object received from server
 * @return corresponding {@link StorylineData}
 */
public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    if (jsonObject != null) {

        StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();


        storylineData.date = jsonObject.optString("date");
        storylineData.caloriesIdle = jsonObject.optInt("caloriesIdle");
        storylineData.lastUpdate = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
        storylineData.summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>();
        storylineData.segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>();



        /**Get the data associated with the array named summary **To get a specific JSONArray: Summary*/
        JSONArray summariesJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");

        if (summariesJsonArray != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < summariesJsonArray.length(); i++) {


            /**each time through array will need to get a reference of current object*/
            JSONObject summaryJsonObject = summariesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

                    if (summaryJsonObject != null) {
                    /**===============Translate data from json to Java=================*/
                        /**Create a new OBJECT OF ARRAY STORYLINE/SUMMARY*/
                        ArrayList<SummaryData> summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop
                        storylineData.setSummary(summary);

                        /**Get summary from json into java*/
                        summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance");

                        /**Get date from json into java*/
                        String date = summaryJsonObject.optString("date");
                        storylineData.setDate(date);

                        /**Get group from json into java*/
                        String group = summaryJsonObject.optString("group");//Get name using key e.g. date
                        storylineData.setGroup(group);

               ...


                        storylineData.summary.add(SummaryData.parse(summaryJsonObject));
                        Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sJo", summaryJsonObject.toString() + "Log\n");
                        System.out.println("print distance" + summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance"));
                        System.out.println("print summary" + summaryJsonObject);


                }
            }

        JSONArray segmentsJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
        if (segmentsJsonArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < segmentsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject segment = segmentsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

                if (segment != null) {

                    ArrayList<SegmentData> segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop
                    storylineData.setSegments(segments);

                    String type = segment.optString("type");
                    storylineData.setType(type);

                  ...

                    storylineData.segments.add(SegmentData.parse(segment));


                    Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sSo", segment.toString());

                }
            }
        }
        return storylineData;
    }
    return null;


}


}
```

I'm wondering if the reason the items are appearing in a single row may be because of a problem in the layout files?

Main Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerAPI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/API_Names"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerAPI"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressRequest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editResponse"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerAPI"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressRequest"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/progressRequest" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/flower_name_placeholder"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ArrayAdapter items display in a single row]

Comment: You can add a screenshot of the list shown to you?

Comment: Yes, add screenshot for better understanding the problem.

Comment: You are sure they are distinct rows? If you press a list item the entire list appears selected? Maybe margins aren't showing, the adapter code seems correct.

Comment: Yes if I press a list item the entire list appears selected. Also the array adapter is never used because if I comment out all the ArrayAdapter code all the items still display in a single row.

Comment: First of all remove the `+` signs before `id`, whereever you are referencing to an already created `id`.
`android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerAPI"` becomes
`android:layout_below="@id/spinnerAPI"`
Use `@+id/` only when you create the id for the first time.

Comment: Thanks I have removed the + signs before id.

Answer (score 0):

Changed MainActivity to implement View.OnClickListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Removed ArrayAdapter and replaced updateResponse method with:

```
public void updateResponse(final String message) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                //MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

                String[] stringArray = message.split("\n");

                // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
                // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
                // array as a third parameter.
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: if your own answer solve your problem, please mark it as solution :)